# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

Getting data from local storage using the `useEffect` hook,
when I tried to parse the data, this error message pop-up:

> Unexpected end of JSON input

[image]

Here is my code

```
const JobsPage = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = window.localStorage.getItem("Job") || [] // get the data from local storage
    setData(storedData)
}, [])

const jobData = JSON.parse(data) || [];
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), `JSON.parse()` parses a JSON string, not any value, while in your case, the `data` state can be equal to `[]`, the initial value, which is an array. This is why you are getting that error.

One way to do what you want is to remove that `JSON.parse(data)` line you have, and change your `useEffect` callback to:

```js
const JobsPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = window.localStorage.getItem("Job");
    if (storedData) {
      try {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData);
        if (Array.isArray(parsedData)) {
          setData(parsedData);
        } else {
          setData([]);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setData([]);
      }
    }
  }, []);
  //...
};
```